# Best way to apply css to table with namespace

Tags: html, css, namespaces

What would be the best approach and shortest traversing technique to apply css to id tblTest taking id divFinder as namespace.

```
<style>
#divFinder table > tr> td > div > table#tblTest{
background-color:red;
} 
</style>

<div id="divFinder">
    <table id="tblFinder">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <span>abc</span>
                <span><label id="lblErrorMessage"></label></span>
                <div >
                    <img src="@Url.Content(Links.Content.Images.icon_png)" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdPickerLeftPanel">
                <div class="divPickerLeftPanel">
                    <table id="tblTest">
```

Comment: If it's an `id` the best and shortest way is to do `#tblTest{}`

Comment: Since the id tblFinder is unique there is no need to namespace it to the div. Anyway i guess you would use `#divFinder #tblFinder` (which is actually nonsense). If you are going to use id's multiple times on your page: **dont** do it. Use `class` instead